# Python3: f-string {} symbols screening

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

i want to use f-string in my python code to write some json, but got a problem with screening {} symbols. What the correct way to screen lonely `{` `}` symbols? For example i want to write:

```
data = f'{[{{prod_id},{quantity},{size}}]}'
```

I cant get how to write it correctly, and basic python screening not working for me for some reason here.

Comment: What do you expect the string that comes out to look like?

Comment: {[{ 1,2,M }]} - this, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape curly braces in f-strings by doubling them, e.g.

```
data = f"{{[{{{prod_id},{quantity},{size}}}]}}"
```